# Squelize - geolocation in where clauses using MariaDB

Tags: node.js, orm, mariadb, sequelize.js

I've got a node.js app , using MariaDB.
So far all my SQL is in Stored Procedures.

I'm considering Sequelize, the only thing I haven't found in there - that I need - is using functions in where clauses.

I've got something like this in my current query :

```
Select * from places p
where ST_WITHIN(p.geolocation, ST_BUFFER(GeomFromText(in_geolocation), radius)) = 1
```

(in_gelocation and radius are SP parameters).

Is there anyway to do this in Sequelize, or another ORM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Sequelize.fn`:

> Creates a object representing a database function. This can be used in
>   search queries, both in **where** and order parts, and as default values
>   in column definitions.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#fn-fn-args-sequelizefn

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Sequelize geolocation example for you to reference.  It utilizes SQL functions and illustrates the inclusion of the where attribute.

```
if(!query.includes(',') && lat && lng) {
    attributes.push([
        DataTypes.fn('concat',
        DataTypes.col('city'),
        DataTypes.col('state')
    ),'city_state'])
    attributes.push([
        DataTypes.fn('ST_Distance',
        DataTypes.col('location'),
        DataTypes.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${lat} ${lng})', 4326)`)
    ), 'distance'])
}
if(!query.includes(',')) {
    attributes.push([DataTypes.literal(`CASE
        WHEN
            name = '` + query + `' THEN 4
        WHEN
            city LIKE '%` + query + `%' THEN 3
        WHEN
            name LIKE '%` + query + `%' THEN 2
        WHEN
            name LIKE '` + query + `%' THEN 1
    END`), 'exact_like_match'])
}
var whereAnd = []
whereAnd.push(
    DataTypes.literal('MATCH(name, city, state, zip) AGAINST(:search_query)')
)
whereAnd.push({
    menu_enabled: 'Y'
})
var search_params = {   
    where: whereAnd,
    replacements: {
        search_query: '+' + query + '*',
        type: DataTypes.QueryTypes.SELECT
    },
    attributes: attributes,
    offset: parseInt(req.query.start),
    limit: req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 12
}
search_params['order'] = [
    DataTypes.literal('exact_like_match DESC')
]
if(!query.includes(',')) {
    // console.log('comma detected!')
    search_params['order'] = [
        DataTypes.literal('exact_like_match DESC, distance ASC')
    ]
}
dispensary.findAndCountAll(search_params).then(disp_rx => {

})
```